# Icon on Shortcut to .NET WinForms application automatically update

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, winforms, icons

I have a VB.NET WinForms application which has a custom icon.  I changed the icon (to something else) in the project's properties, and I can see it is correct on the EXE that is built, but all shortcut's to it retain the old icon.  If I create a new shortcut the icon is correct.

When I try to set the icon on the shortcut manually (using Change Icon in the shortcut's properties) Windows report the error 'The file %1 contains no icons.', which I think may be part of the issue, as it isnt able to locate the icon automatically (so it doesn't update).

What can I do to get the icon on the shortcut to update automatically?

Update: Logging off and on again refreshes the icon cache, and the icons change.  Also calling ie4uinit -ClearFontCache updates the icons, but this doesnt work in newer versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/08/12/how-can-i-change-the-icon-for-an-existing-shortcut.aspx
I'm not sure why you can't delete the old shortcuts and make new ones, but I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't necessarily know where they may reside.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't used anything other than Windows 7 in so long (such a shame, I know) that I wouldn't know what to tell you to do on any other version. If logging off and back on doesn't work, try restarting the machine. That's all that I can think of.

Comment: Logging off and on again *does* work (as noted in my update to the question), but I would rather it be instant. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: No problem. My mistake... I took that to mean that it worked for the older versions of Windows and not the newer versions. As far as I know, logging off and back on is the only way to update the icons for existing shortcuts.